Django+tenant FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
I am currently updating the following error in my application:

FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

This error does not occur all the time, only at certain times of the day.
I have the following database configuration where I use tenants:
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse(DATABASE_URL)}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend'
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 300
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {'MAX_CONNS': 25}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ( 'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter', )

What I don't understand is that when I query the maximum number of connections directly in the database, the number that appears is 1708:
max_connections
And the error starts to pop up when my bank starts to have the number of connections above 400:
dashboard
Initially my backend connection to the database did not have the following settings:
DATABASES\['default'\]\['CONN_MAX_AGE'\] = 300
DATABASES\['default'\]\['OPTIONS'\] = {'MAX_CONNS': 25}

However, I believe that these settings would not affect the tenant.

Your application keeps on opening new database connections, without closing the current idle ones. It doesn't reuse the idle connections either. Consider a connection pool, like pgBouncer.

You can increase the max_connections setting in your PostgreSQL configuration  but this also requires increasing system resources (RAM). make sure you have enough memory to handle more connections.
Consider reducing the CONN_MAX_AGE. because it can  help release connections more quickly except you have a reason to set it to 300
